# Parsing file for a number on UNIX

Tags: string, parsing, unix

Looking for a better way of extracting a number from the last line in a file.
Sample content:

```
# Provider added by blah
#
security.provider.3=org.bouncycastle145.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
#
# Provider added by blah
#
security.provider.4=org.bouncycastle145.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
#
# Provider added by blah
#
security.provider.79=org.bouncycastle145.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
```

I would like to parse the last line in the file and return the number after:
`security.provider.`

This is what I'm using and it seems to only fine the first digit after:
`security.provider.`:

```
tail -1 filename | cut -c19
```

I know I can use:

```
tail -1 filename | cut -c19,20
```

but I wouldn't know if the number is a single digit or double, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your final line is always exactly "security.provider.xxx=" and you want xxx:

```
$ sed -n \$p file | cut -d= -f 1 | cut -d. -f 3
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use sed as:

```
tail -1 file | sed -r 's/security\.provider\.([0-9]+).*/\1/'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using just a `sed` one liner:

```
sed -ne '$s/security\.provider\.\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/p' <file>
```